# Java Selenium HtmlUnitDriver - Gwt source is not populating due to Ajax call

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I am using Java Selenium HtmlUnitDriver for verifying html of Gwt source is not populating due to Ajax call. Is there any way to execute the actual page and get the source of the page? I tried to enable Js but still not getting any success.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle a dynamic content, then your best chance is probably to use a browser/driver with a JavaScript engine. Here is an example the headless PhantomJS driver:

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "...");

WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

// load the page
driver.get("http://...");

// wait for a dynamic element to be created
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("...")));

// get the page source
String source = driver.getPageSource();
```